# keep selected value in dropdown in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html.dropdownlistfor

How to keep selected value in a dropdown
my dropdown id is **"devicePlatform_id"** its values are **Android,Windows,Smart Phone** 
while updation I want selected value chosen by user during saving for eg ***Android***
so how can I do that in Jquery.I have broght data from db just wanted to keep the value 
So what will be the code for that

```
$('#devicePublicationStatus_id'). ??
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .val() function:

```
$('#devicePublicationStatus_id').val("Android");
```

EDIT: I presumed that for "dropdown" you mean a "select" html element with "option" elements as childs.

EDIT2: As the other answer say i have not understand well if you want GET or SET the value in the dropdown. Use .val("Android") for set the current value, and only .val() for get the current value.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right:

```
$('#devicePublicationStatus_id option:selected').val()
```